# Reverse Rectangle Packing

Tags: algorithm, rectangles, vertices, packing

I have a connected shape that consists of squares put together, e.g. take a squared paper and draw a line along the existing lines that ends at its beginning and does not cross itself.

The goal is now to find an algorithm (*not brute-force*) that fills this shape with as few, non-overlapping rectangles as possible.

I'm looking for the optimal solution. As can be seen in the images, the naive greedy approach (take the largest rectangle) does not work.

[image: Optimal]
*(Optimal)*

[image: Greedy]
*(Greedy)*

My scenario is vertices reduction, but I'm sure there are other use-cases as well.

*Note: This problem seems basic, but I was not able to find a solution elsewhere. Also, is this problem NP-hard?*

*Edit: I just realized that, in my scenario, filling the shape with as few non-overlapping **triangles** as possible, would give an even better result.*

Comment: Don't know if this is optimal, but intuitively I think you could scan through the horizontal dimension and count the rectangles building in the horizontal direction, then do the same for the vertical dimension, and take the minimum of the two.

Comment: It sounds similar problem to redraw a partially obscured window, maybe you can find an optimal algorithm in old window manager that did only used rectangular clipping, and not arbitrary mask, like st-80

Comment: Search for 'bin filling algorithms'.

Comment: irrelephant: I do not understand. Could you elaborate further?
aka.nice: Interesting idea. Do you have any window manager in mind that I could have a look at?
TonyHartley: Seems to be a different problem.

Comment: Bin filling (bin packing) use edge heuristics to find optimal fits, I suspect that the best solution to your problem lays in edge pattern analysis. I would try a divide and conquer type method that uses edge analysis and resolution division (i.e. start with 8x8, 4x4, 2x2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've spend a lot of time researching this, since I asked the initial question. For the first problem (optimally filling the shape with rectangles), I've written the solution here under the header "Optimal Greedy Meshing":

http://blackflux.wordpress.com/2014/03/01/meshing-in-voxel-engines-part-2/

The complexity is actually better (faster) than for optimally triangulating a polygon without holes. The slowest part is the Hopcroft-Karp algorithm.

Treating the shape as a polygon is also discussed in the linked blog post. Note that I'm also considering holes.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is harder than the one with triangles; for triangles, see the algorithms in

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation

which can do it without any extra vertices.